# How can I hide calendars from Siri?

Tags: iphone, calendar, ical, siri, google-calendar

When I open the Calendar app, I have some hidden calendars which I don't normally want to see.

But when I ask Siri what meetings I have, it shows me all the events. I don't need to know what my family is doing when I ask about my own meetings:

[image: Screenshot of Siri]
[image: Screenshot of Calendar]

How can I hide some calendars from Siri?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No.

No, at this moment it is not possible to hide calendars from Siri. I highly recommend you send this [feedback to Apple](http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html).

A workaround would be to use a second calendar app to show the calendars of your family and use the normal calendar app only for your own calendars.

Comment: Unfortunately, all my calendars are with google calendar. I'll look for a work around, perhaps sharing one calendar wit another account and using that account with Calendar.app.

Comment: There we go - I've got the google calendar app. I disabled the calendars showing with my gmail account (left mail etc enabled) and then used the iCal link to subscribe to it manually. I can't edit events, but I can always do that in google calendar. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could get you in the right direction :-)

Answer (score 1):

Siri seems to show exactly those events, which are in one of the enabled calendars in the calendar app from apple. So if a calendar is not visible in the app, its not visible to siri either and vice versa.

If you use a second calendar app as your daily driver, you can therefore use the following workaround.

- Setup the calendars in apples calendar app, the way you want Siri to use them.
- Activate different calendars in your third party calendar app as needed.